# How to regroup Series after groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, data-science

After some operations I have a series that i got after grouping by phone number and counting different calls. I need to count the phone numbers that have an equal number of calls. I mean, if there is 5 people who made 3 calls I need to get a series or a dataframe looking like:

```py
num_calls 
3    5
1    100
...
```

My series now looks like

```py
phone_num 
89248089190  5
48048102481  6 
12948148014  2
14091404108  5
```

Comment: It would be a simple `.value_counts()` I believe.

Comment: shall i delete my question now or let it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.value_counts() does that thing

Answer (score 1):

For creating a DataFrame I did the following:

```
numbers = [89248089190, 48048102481, 12948148014, 14091404108]
calls = [5, 6, 2, 5]

df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': numbers,
                   'calls': calls})
```

I then groupby 'calls'

```
num_calls = df.groupby('calls')
```

And then count the number of occurrences

```
count = num_calls.count()


        numbers
calls   
2       1
5       2
6       1
```